# conditionally define constants in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In CodeIgniter, Is it possible to define constants globally with the session checking as in this below example

```
if($this->session->userdata("private")){
    define("TAB_ACCOUNTS","accounts");
    define("TAB_INVENTORY","inventory");
    define("TAB_INVENTORY_PRODUCTS","inventory_products");
    define("TAB_INVENTORY_VIEW","inventory_view");
    define("TAB_ORDER_PRODUCTS","order_products");
    define("TAB_ORDERS","orders");
    define("TAB_ORDERS_VIEW","orders_view");
    define("TAB_VENDORACCOUNTS","vendoraccounts");
}else{
    define("TAB_ACCOUNTS","back_accounts");
    define("TAB_INVENTORY","back_inventory");
    define("TAB_INVENTORY_PRODUCTS","back_inventory_products");
    define("TAB_INVENTORY_VIEW","back_inventory_view");
    define("TAB_ORDER_PRODUCTS","back_order_products");
    define("TAB_ORDERS","back_orders");
    define("TAB_ORDERS_VIEW","back_orders_view");
    define("TAB_VENDORACCOUNTS","back_vendoraccounts");
}
```

My Requirement is to use table name MySQL queries based on the session...

**UPDATE**: I need to declare those constants in config.php or anywhere. I need to access those throughout the project not in a function or in a controller

Comment: "conditional constants", eh? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oxymoron

Comment: Yeah it's fine. I have constants that are determinant on the service layer for example. To Sammitch's point it does sound wrong.

Comment: Did you try this and get a result that made you think it wasn't working, or are you just asking theoretically?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I need to access those throughout the project not in a function or in a controller

Comment: @DhanuK,  you're essentially just wanting a global variable then, not really a constant.  But since constants are global, this will work for you.  I don't know CI well but I'd assume they have a configuration file option for this very purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to have a `session` up and running the easiest solution is to utilize a 'post_controller_constructor' hook.

In *config.php*

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

The file *application/config/hooks.php*

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
  'class' => '',
  'function' => 'set_tab_constants',
  'filename' => 'post_controller_hook.php',
  'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

In the file *application/hooks/post_controller_hook.php*

```
function set_tab_constants()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['private']))
    {
        define("TAB_ACCOUNTS", "accounts");
        define("TAB_INVENTORY", "inventory");
        define("TAB_INVENTORY_PRODUCTS", "inventory_products");
        define("TAB_INVENTORY_VIEW", "inventory_view");
        define("TAB_ORDER_PRODUCTS", "order_products");
        define("TAB_ORDERS", "orders");
        define("TAB_ORDERS_VIEW", "orders_view");
        define("TAB_VENDORACCOUNTS", "vendoraccounts");
    }
    else
    {
        define("TAB_ACCOUNTS", "back_accounts");
        define("TAB_INVENTORY", "back_inventory");
        define("TAB_INVENTORY_PRODUCTS", "back_inventory_products");
        define("TAB_INVENTORY_VIEW", "back_inventory_view");
        define("TAB_ORDER_PRODUCTS", "back_order_products");
        define("TAB_ORDERS", "back_orders");
        define("TAB_ORDERS_VIEW", "back_orders_view");
        define("TAB_VENDORACCOUNTS", "back_vendoraccounts");
    }
}
```

Directly accessing the superglobal `$_SESSION` avoids the overhead of getting an instance of `CI` so that the `session` class can be used to read `userdata`. That method directly reads the `$_SESSION` variable anyway. Avoid the middle-man and buy direct!

In PHP the scope of a constant is global. You can access constants anywhere in your script without regard to scope.

Comment: You'll have to figure out where the second attempted defines are happening. I don't see how the code above would attempt that.

Comment: sorry i forgetted to remove same constanats in config this cause error,thank you you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can see, your public/backend tables (the `else` block) are always prefixed with `back_`, so I would recommend not using these constants.

Instead, use the normal table name in your models and create a single method that verifies the session and returns an empty string or the "back_" string, and then use this method in your "from" clause.

In other words: *" why having a lot of constants when the only difference is a string prefix?"*

---

Plus, be careful with your requisite if these mirrored tables represent the same records, for instance, if records at `accounts` table are the same kind/type of the records in `back_accounts` I understand they should be all the same table. :-) I'm supposing you can't change this requisite :-)